# Is it possible to get the position of views inside ViewHolder for the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

The ViewHolder I have contains views that are needed for each item of my RecycleView, which are two TextViews, PlayPauseView, and AppCompatSeekBar. In the constructor I have initialized them to their ids of my layout, and is ready for my Adapter class to extend it. The problem is I have this PlayPauseView that needs to be toggled at the correct position for it to function right, because if I press the view at another position, the previous position is still toggled. Here's an image for better understanding.

[image]

The yellow means that it is currently playing, but two cannot play at the same time so I was hoping to get the position of the view inside the RecyclerView item.

This is from the Holder class

```
TextView mInstrumentalName, mProducer;
PlayPauseView mPlayButton; // Need to add pause/stop
AppCompatSeekBar mMusicSeekbar;

ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public TrackHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mInstrumentalName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.instrumental_name);
    mProducer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.producer);
    mPlayButton = (PlayPauseView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
    mMusicSeekbar = (AppCompatSeekBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.music_seekbar);



    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

This is from the Adapter class

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TrackHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.mInstrumentalName.setText(tracks.get(position).getInstrumentalName());
    holder.mProducer.setText(tracks.get(position).getProducer());


    holder.mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.mPlayButton.toggle();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                mediaPlayer.reset();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tracks.get(position).getMusicLink());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } else {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tracks.get(position).getMusicLink());
                    previous_link = tracks.get(position).getMusicLink();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }


        }
    });

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
            Toast.makeText(context, Integer.toString(tracks.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yea its possible can you show your code ?

Comment: Yeah sure, I've added it now.

Comment: and what is your question actually? what do you mean by `"position of view inside ViewHolder"`?

Comment: @pskink Like I want to be able to retoggle the PlayPauseView in position 0 while also toggling the PlayPauseView in position 2.

Comment: so use `ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()` method

Comment: Nah that's not what I was looking for. I can't manipulate the view at the position with that method. holder.mPlayButton.getAdapterPosition().toggle() wouldn't work.

Comment: yeah, it returns 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 because I have 5 items in my recyclerview. The problem is I want to toggle the PlayPauseView at position 2 for example. How would I do that? 09-12 14:04:48.183 17495-17495/? D/position: 0
09-12 14:04:48.193 17495-17495/? D/position: 1
09-12 14:04:48.213 17495-17495/? D/position: 2
09-12 14:04:48.233 17495-17495/? D/position: 3
09-12 14:04:48.243 17495-17495/? D/position: 4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get position in your view holder class then you can call `getAdapterPosition()` inside your class. this will return you the clicked position in view holder class

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. So what I did instead of focusing on the views inside of the ViewHolder, I refreshed/updated the whole item in the RecyclerView, meaning it will refresh the toggle state of the previous item. Here's a code snipped if anyone in the future has any trouble on the same question.

```
            private int start_notifying = 0;
            private int previous_pos = -1;
```

So start notifying is at 0 because you don't want to refresh the item until you toggled the play button at least once, and set the current position to become the previous position when you want to press a different list item. You then increment so you can start refreshing items on the next item pressed. Using notifyItemChanged(previous_pos) refreshed the item of the previous position that was pressed, making the play button go back to its normal state.

```
            if (start_notifying > 0) {
                notifyItemChanged(previous_pos);
                previous_pos = position;
            } else {
                previous_pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                Log.d("previous_pos", Integer.toString(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
                start_notifying++;
            }
```